# Como utilizar valor da variavel em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problema em utilizar o valor que esta dentro da minha variável quando eu a utilizo jquery

```
var id_pais =  $('#endUF option[value=id_pais]').text();
        $('#endUF option[value=id_pais]').remove();
        $('#endPAIS option[value=id_pais]').prop('selected', true);
```

No caso eu pego o valor do meu sistema e coloco em uma variável js. Mas depois não consigo reutiliza-la no jquery.
Li andando a respeito e vi que quanto utilizo value no jquery, como o usado acima, o jquery o vê como uma string e não pega o valor da varável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou concatenar a variável.
Tente o seguinte:

```
var id_pais =  $('#endUF option[value=' + id_pais + ']').text();
        $('#endUF option[value=' + id_pais + ']').remove();
        $('#endPAIS option[value=' + id_pais + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Era isso mesmo, mas tive problema na utilização de Strings na variáveis. Tive melhor resultado ao utilizar números.

Comment: Beleza. Que bom que conseguiu resolver. ;)